# Incluir espaços ao ler strings em C

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Boas pessoal

Tenho um trabalho em C para fazer, em que tenho que ler informações dum txt.com muitas entradas diferentes.
Cada string segue o seguinte formato:

```
12345António Manuel Silva Mendes                        Frankfurt  Varsovia    1
```

Tem sempre um inteiro de 5 caracteres para a identificação, 51 caracteres para o nome (incluindo espaços), 11 para a cidade de partida, 11 para a de chegada e um inteiro com no máximo 2 dígitos para a data.

declaro a estrutura assim:

```
typedef struct bilhete{

    int BI;
    char nome[51];
    char partida[11];
    char chegada[11];
    int data;

}BILHETE;
```

e estou a ler do ficheiro assim:

```
while(!feof(fp)){

        fscanf(fp,"%d%51c%11c%11c%d\n", &bilhete.BI, bilhete.nome, bilhete.partida, bilhete.chegada, &bilhete.data);
```

Acontece que estou a fazer um printf de debug do bilhete.nome, e ele não está a imprimir correctamente. Como fazer para reconhecer os espaços em branco?

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar o %[^\n]s, exemplo:
Na expressão de formatação, ao invés de usar %51s para a "string", use %51[^\n]s.

Comment: Obrigado, já deu. No entanto o bilhete.partida e o bilhete.chegada não estão a ser impressos. Alguma sugestão?